# Want subquery to return non-Null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables I am using in a query; `AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE` , `AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE` , and `PO_HEADERS_ALL` as a subquery.

The AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE table is joined to PO_HEADERS_ALL only on the `PO_NUMBER` from AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE to the `SEGMENT1` in PO_HEADERS_ALL.  I want to populate the column 'REQ_BU_ID2' with the REQ_BU_ID value based on `SEGMENT1` equaling `LN.PO_NUMBER` where it is not `NULL`.

```
SELECT HDR.INVOICE_ID  , HDR.PO_NUMBER , LN.PO_NUMBER LN_PO_NUMBER

, (SELECT PO2.REQ_BU_ID
    FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL PO2
    WHERE PO2.SEGMENT1 = LN.PO_NUMBER
       AND PO2.REQ_BU_ID IS NOT NULL
       AND LN.PO_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
       --AND HDR.PO_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
       AND rownum = 1    ) REQ_BU_ID2

FROM AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE HDR
INNER JOIN AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE LN ON LN.INVOICE_ID = HDR.INVOICE_ID
AND HDR.INVOICE_ID = 300000136747640
```

I want to populate the `REQ_BU_ID2` (non-null) value for rows even when the `LN.PO_NUMBER` is `NULL` so I thought by using the `AND LN.PO_NUMBER IS NOT NULL` condition in the Subquery would then only return the non-null value, however as you can see it is still returning `Null` as well in the results:

**Current Results from above query:**

[image]

**Desired Results:**
[image]

**Edit:**

```
INVOICE_ID        REQ_BU_ID2        PO_NUMBER   LN_PO_NUMBER
300000136747640   300000006290049               K11004499
300000136747640
300000136747640
300000136747640   300000006290049               K11004499
```

Comment: If a correlated sub-query doesn't find ANY rows, it returns NULL. Are you certain there ***are*** rows to be returned from the sub-query?

Comment: Please read this, then edit your question: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't want the outer query to exclude the 2 middle rows though. I still want them in output, however I need to be able to populate the REQ_BU_ID2 value in the Top and Bottom rows that has the same INVOICE_ID with into the ones that are blank that don't have a LN_PO_NUMBER value populated. Hope that makes sense, I think the Desired Results picture may illustrate it better.

Comment: Also, if you're limiting the results to just one row, you should enforce a sort-order with `ORDER BY` and probably use `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` rather than `rownum=1`

Comment: Is it ***always guaranteed*** that all rows with the same `invoice_id` have the same `ln_po_number` and so will get the same `REQ_BU_ID`?  Or can multiple rows have the same `invoice_id` and different `REQ_BU_ID`?

Comment: There are rows in the `AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE` that have rows with a LN_PO_NUMBER and rows without as well for the same INVOICE_ID, that is the challenge because I still want to populate the REQ_BU_ID2 value from the rows that do have the ln_po_number populated.

Comment: Fix the images of data and I'll add an answer using lateral joins and window functions, guaranteeing that all rows with the same `invoice_id` will lookup the same `req_bu_id`

Comment: Hi @MatBailie I made an Edit to the original post above with the data in table format. Hope this is ok.... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below uses a CTE to give all `INVOICE_ID`s the same `LN_PO_NUMBER`.

If they can legitimately ***ever*** have different "non-NULL" `PO_NUMBER`s, this won't work.

Then your sub-query has been adapted to use `ORDER BY REQ_BU_ID DESC FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` in order to find exactly one `REQ_BU_ID` in a deterministic way, preferring non-NULL values.

Again, if any `PO_NUMBER` can legitimately relate to more than 1 non-NULL `REQ_BU_ID`, this won't work.

Also, if ZERO `REQ_BU_ID` are found, it still returns `NULL`.

```
WITH
  PO_LOOKUP
AS
(
  SELECT
    HDR.INVOICE_ID,
    HDR.PO_NUMBER,
    MAX(LN.PO_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY HDR.INVOICE_ID)   AS LN_PO_NUMBER
  FROM
    AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE        HDR
  INNER JOIN
    AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE   LN
      ON LN.INVOICE_ID = HDR.INVOICE_ID
)
SELECT
  PO_LOOKUP.*,
  (
    SELECT REQ_BU_ID
      FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL
     WHERE SEGMENT1 = PO_LOOKUP.LN_PO_NUMBER
  ORDER BY REQ_BU_ID ASC
     FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  )
    AS REQ_BU_ID
FROM
  PO_LOOKUP
WHERE
  INVOICE_ID = 300000136747640
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/N9fb6W9I

***EDIT:*** Alternatively...

```
SELECT
  HDR.INVOICE_ID,
  HDR.PO_NUMBER,
  LN.MAX_PO_NUMBER,
  PO.MAX_REQ_BU_ID
FROM
  AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE        HDR
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE.*,
    MAX(PO_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID)  AS MAX_PO_NUMBER
  FROM
    AP_INVOICE_LINES_INTERFACE
)
  LN
    ON LN.INVOICE_ID = HDR.INVOICE_ID
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    SEGMENT1,
    MAX(REQ_BU_ID)   AS MAX_REQ_BU_ID
  FROM
    PO_HEADERS_ALL
  GROUP BY
    SEGMENT1
)
  PO
    ON PO.SEGMENT1 = LN.MAX_PO_NUMBER
WHERE
  HDR.INVOICE_ID = 300000136747640
```

Comment: Hi @MatBailie I am getting a syntax error for missing Right Parenthesis on Oracle DB.

Comment: Thanks @MatBillie, this seems to work as desired! Just curious if this be any kind of performance issue using CTE with window function? I will have to run this on a larger data set ultimately with additional columns in the main query.

Comment: That totally depends on your table indexes, data cardinality, etc.  As it's partitioning by the same column as in the join, I'd expect any performance issues to come from the join, not the window function.